# Detecting a very low current vs open wire

Tags: current, detection

I am working with a few 0.333V CT and at times, the operating current is very very very low, near 0. I need to be able to detect between a very low amp reading vs an open wire. Is there a way to do this with this type of CT? I've been thinking about this for a bit and can't think of anything.

The turns ratio of the CT doesn't matter for this question, the secondary is always a 0-333mVAC and the range of the CTs change based on my application, so just consider near 0mVac. I need to detect the difference between very close to 0amp vs open wire. Simply setting a low limit doesn't work in this case.

I want to shut my equipment off if I detect an open wire, but not with a 0 reading, so I am looking for an effective way to tell the difference.

Thank you

Comment: Is the operating current AC only ?

Comment: Can you provide a basic schematic of the circuit you refer to ?

Comment: Can you add a link to a spec sheet for the transformer to your question please. Also, 'very very very low' is open to interpretation , can you give us a value or a range of values?

Answer (score 1):

You have two unknowns and one measurement.

Your two unknowns are the open/closed state of the circuit you're observing, and the current in the wire.

Your one measurement is the AC voltage on your current transformer.

Two unknowns and one measurement means you can't get there from here.

You need to find another measurement.  Exactly what that is depends on the equipment that you're working on.  You need to find some characteristic of the wire you're looking at that varies with the open vs. closed state, then you need to find a way to sense it.

You could:

- Look at the AC voltage on the wire itself, and compare it to some reference (if that'll work).
- Inject some current *into* your current transformer and measure the voltage (if that'll (A) work, and (B) won't kill people or equipment).
- Do something that I'm either not clever enough to think of, or can't think of because I don't know enough about the equipment.